Looking for the specific font in the screen shot
I came across one paper with a very pleasing font and formatting. I tried many different fonts available but couldn't find the exact match. I also like the spacing and linewidth. I would appreciate your help identifying these items! 
The full paper is here https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.14953

it's arxiv so you can download the full tex source and use exactly the same fonts and style just use the link you put in the question and click on the TeX Source link in the right sidebar

Otherwise, you could try a service such as the one provided by https://www.whatfontis.com.

brilliant! i never thought of downloading the Tex source files. thanks! @DavidCarlisle

@Clément thanks! this is really useful

I have reproduced for 80% your desidered output. I have used XCharter-Math and for calligraphy font Asana Math.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XCharter}
\setmathfont{XCharter-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal},
             Alternate,
             Scale=MatchUppercase]
            {Asana Math}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Semimeasures.} A semimeasure is a probability measure $P$ over infinite and finite sequences $\mathcal{X}^{\infty}\cup \mathcal{X}^*$ for some finite alphabet $X$ assumed to be $\{0,1\}$ (most statements hold for arbitrary finite $\mathcal{X}$). Let $\mu(x)$ be the probability that an (in)finite sequence starts with $x.$ While proper distributions satisfy $\sum_{a\in \mathcal{X}}\mu(xa)=\mu(x)$, semimeasures exhibit probability gaps and satisfy $\sum_{\alpha\in \mathcal{X}}\mu(xa)\leq\mu(x).$
\textbf{Turing Machines}. A Turing Machine (TM) takes a string of symbols $z$ as an input, and outputs a string of symbols $x$ (after reading $z$ and halting), i.e. $T(z)=x.$ For convenience we define the output string at computation step s as $T^s(z)=x$ which may be the empty string $\epsilon$ We adopt similar notation for Universal Turing Machines $U$. Monotone TMs (see Definition 1 below) are special TMs that can incrementally build the output string while incrementally reading the input program, which is a convenient practical property we exploit in our experiments.
\end{document} 



Tt's arxiv so you can download the full tex source and use exactly the same fonts and style just use the link you put in the question and click on the TeX Source link in the right sidebar.
